# how I divide df['2'] by df['1'] throughout a whole column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find the change in nav in my dataframe by dividing each index by the previous index. I'm new to this and am stumped! Hope you can help. Thanks!

```
t1 = 0
d = []
for f in final_df['nav']:
    t = float(f)
    d.append(t / t1)
    t1 = t
print(d)
```

Comment: `df['2'] / df['1']`

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit and show what is the content of `df['1']` and `df['2']`? Also, what would be the expected result? Do you want a list or a new column in the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) on the series.

```
d = final_df['nav'] / final_df['nav'].shift(-1)
```

You'll have to figure out what to do with the last item though, as there's nothing to divide by.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the .shift method for the denominator. This will move the values down by one.

In the example below what happens is 
500 / NaN = NaN 
415 / 500 = .83 
293 / 415 = .71 
... and so forth

```
df = df = pd.DataFrame({'value1':[500,415,293,126,115,140,90,190,217]})

# the first row will be NaN
# the first row of the df['value2'].shift() will be empty 
# if you have a value for the first row you can fill it with .fillna(value for first row denomenator)
df['new_value'] = df['value1'] / df['value1'].shift() # .fillna(value of first denomenator)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Try divided by shift

```
from pandas import pandas as pd

final_df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                   "Col2": [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
                   "nav": [3, 6, 9, 27, 108]},
                  index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-01-05"))
final_df["change"] = final_df["nav"].div(final_df["nav"].shift(1))

print(final_df)

            Col1  Col2  nav  change
2020-01-01    10    13    3     NaN
2020-01-02    20    23    6     2.0
2020-01-03    15    18    9     1.5
2020-01-04    30    33   27     3.0
2020-01-05    45    48  108     4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement a loop function for this, use the pandas [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) function

```
df['nav'].pct_change()
```